# Should I be using this to export the data using the SQL Developer 'Data Pump Export Wizard' connected as a DBA?

Tags: oracle, docker

I am trying to learn more about Oracle databases in my spare time.  I have Oracle Enterprise available in a Docker Container.  I am a developer rather than a DBA.  I have plenty of experience with SQL Server.

I am trying to use the data pump feature.  So far I have done this:

1. Created a user called dummy and created a table (Dummy.table1).
2. Added a few rows to table1.
3. Created a user called admin and given this user dba access.
4. Login to SQL Developer as admin and select: View/DBA.
5. Connect to my database and use Data Pump Export Wizard to create a dump file.
6. Generate a .sql file from the .dmp file.

I have tried all four options (Database; Tablespaces; Schemas and Tabeles) under: 'Types to be exported in data pump', selecting 'Data and DDL' each time, however I cannot see the INSERT statements, which should be created for Dummy.table1.  Why is this?

The only thing I can think of is that there is a menu item called: Tools\Database Export.  Should I be using this to export the data? I would of thought that the data should be exported when using the Data Pump Export Wizard; connected as a DBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Pump stores definitions and data in dumpfiles with a binary format specific to Oracle. Data Pump can be used to generate DDL SQL statements (create user, table, view, trigger, etc.), but not for the data in tables.

If you want INSERT statements, then yes, use the Database Export feature of SQL Developer instead of Data Pump.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you point me to some docs that explain this?

Comment: The oracle documentation portal is at 'https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html'.  Select the oracle version from the drop-list.  After you get the list for your version of oracle. look for a link for 'books' (format of page is slightly different for diff. versions).  Look for the "Utilities" manual, and the section on Data Pump.  This is the actual utility that SQL Dev is executing for you.